# Source Code for Two Dimmensional Array in i for iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone

I want to create meachanical units convertor calculator in iphone sdk so i have to perform one to many type of operation. for example Length is category and there is multiple type of units in Length category for ex.meter,kilometer etc.Now for every unit i will have to create multiple combinations for that i'm using if-else conditions for now to work but practially this increases my code a lot because as there are almost 30 categories and each category has multiple units.So is there any another way to solve this problem in short way as it is too hectic to write so many if else combinations in my code. For this i thought that it might be possible to use two dimensional array.so please provide me code for two dimensional array to perform this calulation operation.

Comment: Arrays are just like C arrays, do you mean NSArray or NSMutableArray?

Comment: First understand, SO is not a GIVE_ME_CODE kind of site..

Comment: @Krishnabhara:-i need to know the code for how to implement two dimensional array in iphone sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put NSArray objects in an NSArray and you have your 2 dimenensional array. (pretty much like in any other language.)

```
NSMutableArray * myTwoDimensionalArray = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[myTwoDimensionalArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value 0/0", @"value 0/1",nil]];    
[myTwoDimensionalArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value 1/0", @"value 1/1",nil]];

// to get value at [i][j]
[[myTwoDimensionalArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j];
```

Answer (score 1):

As jules has suggested you can use a NSMutableArray yo create your 2-d array. Another approach would be to have `mXn` number of objects in a single NSMUtableArray. Create a array and add objects sequentially. Access the `[i][j]` element by accessing the object at `(i*n)+j`.